# Which items are the most profitable for convoys?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So now that I've fleshed out my homestead with a whole bunch of people who can craft a whole plethora of items, I'm keen to find out which ones are the most profitable.

Currently, I'm finding that bandages are very profitable, almost £700 odd a trip.

Which items will net me the highest profit?

Comment: All that cash and nothing to spend it on...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to finish Myriam's Homestead Missions. Now you need to have 3 Land Convoys constructed AND have purchased the extra slots to carry more items in the convoys.

Make sure all the Forts are Liberated and all the districts Liberated in New York.

Now head to your ledger and purchase the following supplies from Myriam:
Bear Pelts x10 - Total Cost £2400
Beaver Pelts x10 - Total Cost £1600
Deer Pelts x10 - Total Cost £1200
Total Investment - £5200

Now head to your convoys and load up the first convoy with 9 Bear Pelts going to Rhinelander's Sugar in New York.
Now load the second with your last Bear Pelt and 8 Beaver Pelts,
and finally your final convoy with the last 2 Beaver Pelts and 7 Deer Pelts.

You may have more of any of these pelts simply from your animal hunting in the Frontier, but lets assume for this example you only have what's purchased.

You will receive the following return on your convoys:
Convoy 1 - £11,232
Convoy 2 - £7,904
Convoy 3 - £6032
Total Profit after initial Investment: ***+£19,968***

You can repeat this every 15 minutes or so, from any ledger at any General Store to get enough money to buy anything you could possibly need in the game.

Comment: Isn't the max number of slots  for land convoys 8? That would make for a convoy with 8 bear pelts, the next with 2 bear pelts + 6 beaver pelts and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you send a full capacity naval convoy with loaded with artillery to the Virgin Islands, you make around £1638 for each individual one. That means each convoy is £24570.

Answer (score 1):

Bear pelts can be farmed from the southwest corner of Packwnack at the river and little island. Then use the ship convoy to St. Augustine. 1560 pounds per pelt over 18k per boat (12 pelts) I usually farm 48 or 96 pelts and then let the convoys do the rest!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your naval convoy to full capacity then fill IT with bear pelts, each convoy fully upgraded has 15 slots and each bear pelt sold to the right person is Worth 1540$ meaning that a filled convoy will bring You a profit of...23400 pounds!

PS:to decrease the risk percent do all the naval missions and to decrease the tax percent liberate all forts

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade convoys to max capacity. Buy bear pelts from Myriam. Sell to general store. 6000 per convoy

Answer (score 0):

Send as many bear pelts as you can with the naval convoy, especially if you have the naval capacity upgrade.

Comment: Should the bear pelts be sent to any particular destination? Do you know how much a fully upgraded naval convoy might earn?

Comment: @Jawbreaker11619 - This isn't a very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to make a lot of fine clothing it sells for about 1950 to the Virgin Islands. Then go make as many fine shoes as possible - they sell for about 1400 to (If I remember correctly) Lundenburg. It's good money and it was just a bunch of leftovers I had from selling all my bear pelts. Then I saw that these where more expensive... On my fully upgraded ship convoy with fully stocked fine clothes it was getting me close to 40k a run.

Answer (score 0):

killing bears or buying pelt is somewhat not affordable so u can craft swords.... u will need level 3 big dave and other resources at very cheap cost from lance and norris.... each sword set will be sold at 1148£ if i sold it to the bahamas using NAVAL convoys not land convoys.... for each convoy u will get 11480£.....

Answer (score 0):

You can craft hoes by going to connors basement, there you will find a red accounting book. You can sell the hoes to any merchant, they sell for an remarkable price. I recommend selling it on a Naval convoy.

Answer (score 0):

The most profitable item in assasins creed 3 is officer swords a single officer sword sent to New York gives you 1950£, imagine filling your convoy with that, about 9000£ from every convoy